# Import CSV files into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Basically, I want to import hundreds of CSV files into SQL Server 2008.

File format is as following :

```
<Ticker>,<DTYYYYMMDD>,<Open>,<High>,<Low>,<Close>,<Volume>
AAM,20120110,21.6,22.8,21.4,21.6,3510
AAM,20120109,22.2,22.9,22.0,22.2,1130
AAM,20120105,0.0,23.0,22.2,22.2,210
```

I tried :

```
BULK
INSERT BBB
FROM 'D:\FIFA\excel_aam.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '/n'
)
GO
```

but it didn't work. So I was thinking import the CSV file as `varchar` format, then change each columns to proper data type later, like this :

```
CREATE TABLE BBB (
TICKER VARCHAR(15)NULL,
INDEXDATE VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
OPENPRICE VARCHAR(15) NULL,
HIGHPRICE VARCHAR(15) NULL,
LOWPRICE VARCHAR(15) NULL,
CLOSEPRICE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
VOLUME VARCHAR(15))
GO
```

but it gave me the error :

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 7 (VOLUME).

So, how could I import these files (so many files that i couldn't use import and export wizard) into SQL Server properly?

Comment: not yet, thanks, I'm just Sql beginner...

Comment: SSIS is not SQL. I suggest searching for the term and learning about this SQL Server feature.

Answer (score 0):

For importing so many files sounds like u'll need [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine in my case when I just **change** the rowterminator to `\n` (**not** `/n`)

```
--CREATE TABLE BBB (
--TICKER VARCHAR(15)NULL,
--INDEXDATE DATETIME,
--OPENPRICE DECIMAL(12,4),
--HIGHPRICE DECIMAL(12,4),
--LOWPRICE DECIMAL(12,4),
--CLOSEPRICE DECIMAL(12,4),
--VOLUME DECIMAL(20,4))
--GO

BULK INSERT BBB
FROM 'D:\FIFA\excel_aam.csv'
WITH
(
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

(3 row(s) affected)
```

and I have the rows in the `BBB` table now....

Comment: Strangely that when i used this code with the "original" file, it's always 0 row affected, but when i deleted the last row, it's successful, i tried it with some files and the same errors.